# Can an AWS S3 Static Site access REST API in VPC?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vpc

I've read through quite a few pages of documentation and other StackOverflow questions/answers but can't seem to come across anything that can help me with my scenario.

I'm hosting a public, static site in an S3 bucket. This site makes some calls to an API that I have hosted in an EC2-instance in a VPC. Because of this, my API can only be called by other instances and services in the same VPC.

But I'm not sure how to allow the S3 Bucket site access to my API.

I've tried creating VPC Endpoints and going down that route, but all that did was restrict access to my S3 site from only the instances within my VPC (which is not what I want).

I would appreciate any help with this, thank you so much.
Hopefully my question is clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, S3 Static Websites are 100% client side code. So it's basically just html + css + javascript being delivered, as-is from S3. If you want to get dynamic content into your website, you need to look at calling an API accessible from your user's browser, i.e. from the internet.

AWS [API Gateway with Private Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html) could be used to accept the incoming REST call and send it on to your EC2 Server in your VPC.

My preferred solution to adding dynamic data to S3 Static Websites is using API Gateway with AWS Lambda to create a serverless website. This minimises running costs, maintenance, and allows for quick deployments. See [The Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/getting-started/) for getting up and running with this solution.

Comment: Wow, it seems so obvious now. I didn't really stop to think this one through. "...from your user's brower..." that's the key right there. Thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

A static site doesn't run on a server. It runs entirely in the web browser of each site visitor. The computer it is running on would be the laptop of your end-user. None of your code runs in the S3 bucket. The S3 bucket simply stores the files and serves them to the end-user's browser which then runs the code. The route you are going down to attempt to give the S3 bucket access to the VPC resource is not going to work.

You will need to make your API publicly accessible in order for code running in your static site (running in web browsers, on end-user's laptops/tablets/phones/etc.) to be able to access it. You should look into something like API keys or JWT tokens to provide security for your public API.